# Next js app hosted in subdirectory with firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, next.js, blogs, firebase-hosting

How to deploy a Next js powered blog on a subdirectory using firebase hosting?

Essentially what I want:

- Landing page is next js app deployed to example.com
- Blog is Next js app deployed to example.com/blog

So when user visits example.com the landing page next js app is rendering, and when user visits example.com/blog it renders the root page from Blog next js app

Currently the blog is deployed to a subdomain blog.example.com using firebase hosting but I have been told for best SEO it is best to have a blog in subdirectory.

**What I have tried:**
Changing Next js base path for Blog in next.config is not a solution since than it will serve 404 on example.com instead of landing page.

I'm thinking firebase hosting rewrites is a solution using cloud function but not 100% clear how to implement it. Plus unclear if it effect negatively for SEO.

Answer from firebase team would be super helpful since I couldn't find any official docs section for this exact scenario.

Comment: If you're looking for a walkthrough tutorial, Stack Overflow isn't the right place to be.  But if you explain what you've done so far and what's not working the way you expect, including your steps to reproduce the error (a  [complete minimal reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)), you're more likely to get specific help.